# Returning 2 Json lists and accessing the data?

Tags: c#, json

I'm returning 2 lists like so:

```
return Json(new { FirstList = allLocations, SecondList = openingHours }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But when i try and access the data being returned, i am getting no values

```
        success: function (data) {
            for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
                console.log(data[index].FirstList.LocationName);
```

any help would be great

Comment: What type is FirstList… is it a collection?

Comment: Try putting the following your javascript code in your success function... `console.log(data);` That will tell you exactly what your webservice is returning to you and will help us in determining the issue

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to concatenate two different JSON objects into one? If that's the case, you need to deserialize the individual objects first, then combine them into a new JSON object.

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new [] {JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(FirstList), JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(SecondList)})
```

This should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Looks more like he tries to serialize an anonymous object into a JSON. Btw. I think he is using the Json method of ASP.Net’s Controller class and not Json.Net (at least not directly)